# change position of a view programatically?

Tags: android

I have read many docs to move a view from its current position to another, but every time I got crashes, I used LayoutParams, but still it get crashes. Any suggestion will be helpful & appreciable. Thnks in advance ....

Comment: can you post the part of the code where you move the view?

Answer (score 0):

A animation translation example here

http://iserveandroid.blogspot.fr/2010/12/slide-up-down-translate.html